# RedisConnectionException: No connection is available to service this operation: EVAL

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm trying to implement Redis in an ASP.NET WebForms application (4.7.2). I downloaded the SessionProvider source code from https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers. I'm using StackExchange.Redis 2.0+ .

After the login has been executed, this error is thrown:

[image]

Apparently, an attempt to `eval` some Lua script was made, and it failed (that was the conclusion for the closure of the [StackExchange.Redis related issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/292)).

So, assuming that assumption is correct, I extracted the offending script, and ran it with `redis-cli --eval` along with the keys and arguments.

```
local retArray = {} 
local lockValue = ARGV[1] 
local locked = redis.call('SETNX',KEYS[1],ARGV[1])        
local IsLocked = true

if locked == 0 then
    lockValue = redis.call('GET',KEYS[1])
else
    redis.call('EXPIRE',KEYS[1],ARGV[2])
    IsLocked = false
end

retArray[1] = lockValue
if lockValue == ARGV[1] then retArray[2] = redis.call('HGETALL',KEYS[2]) else retArray[2] = '' end

local SessionTimeout = redis.call('HGET', KEYS[3], 'SessionTimeout')
if SessionTimeout ~= false then 
    retArray[3] = SessionTimeout 
    redis.call('EXPIRE',KEYS[2], SessionTimeout) 
    redis.call('EXPIRE',KEYS[3], SessionTimeout) 
else 
    retArray[3] = '-1' 
end

retArray[4] = IsLocked
return retArray
```

It was successful.

[image]

Are there other issues that might throw this exception?

EDIT: Upgraded to 2.0. Still suffering from the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to research for your issue, and then I found there is an issue [No connection is available to service this operation using v.1.2.6 #762](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/762) of GitHub `StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis` repo which seems to be same with yours.

According to the note of a comment at the bottom of the GitHub issue, the other issue The ["network stability" / 2.0 / "pipelines" rollup issue #871](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/871), there are some bugs need to be fixed for the version under `2.0`, which likes `network connection stability` issue.

So I suggested that you can upgrade your current `StackExchange.Redis (V1.2.6)` to a latest stable `2.x` version and try your code again. Meanwhile, please notice the [`Release Notes`](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/wiki/Release-Notes) of `Azure/aspnet-redis-providers` to make the right and compatible versions to support your current code.

Comment: Sadly, the 2.+ packages suffer from other issues I am unable to work around (see [this](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1296)). In short, even when using Nuget to download packages and dependencies, it still fails to find certain specific versions of dlls (such as `System.Memory`)

Comment: Updated (through a _lot_ of effort) to the 2.0+ packages, and now I have the exact same issue :(